# Moving an object from A to B from an angle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Firstly, I am working on windows phone sensors

- compass
- accelerometer

I am using Yaw to get my heading in 2D and my object is a simple triangular polygon shape displayed on screen which rotates too when ever I rotate. When I press UP, the shape move forward depends on where it was pointing at. e.g, 115 degrees

Windows Phone in terms of angle has it's 0 up north of the phone and not on the right side.

Now my problem was if I press the UP button, it moves to the wrong direction. I have here my computation for determining the location of the object

```
float radian = e.Attitude.Yaw;
p3d.X += Math.Sin(radian) * 1;
p3d.Y += Math.Cos(radian) * 1;
```

Is this correct?
What is the best way to move an object from A to B from a specified angle?

-UPDATE-
@ctacke - *Sorry but I just want to be specific on the problem so I added **C# Windows Phone Xna** on the title. This question has been asked a lot of times (maybe) but I want to make other users have a quick idea of the problem, that this is for Xna in Windows Phone.*

Comment: 1.) Is `e.Attitude.Yaw` returning radians properly, or possibly degrees?
2.) Normally X is calculated using Cosine, and Y with Sine. But maybe this is intentional because you said it's rotated 90 degrees on the WPhone.
3.) The * 1 isn't really necessary on either line, but isn't part of your problem either.

Comment: Thanks Nic. The 1 is there for speed/velocity and Yaw returns the radian.

Comment: @Skami. Thanks. How do I accept your edit?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just by answering my question
this is what I did

```
float radian = e.Attitude.Yaw;
p3d.X += Math.Cos(radian - MathHelper.ToRadian(90)) * 1;
p3d.Y += Math.Sin(radian - MathHelper.ToRadian(90)) * 1;
```

@Nic gave me an idea about it. Thanks Nic Foster